# Woher kommt die Redensart "eine Leiche im Keller haben"?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Über Menschen, die etwas zu verbergen oder zu verheimlichen haben, hört man manchmal, dass sie eine "Leiche im Keller" haben. Zum Beispiel hier in einem Bericht über die Steuerfahndung:

> Wer noch eine Leiche im Keller hatte, konnte bis zu dem Zeitpunkt, da der Prüfer die Schwelle zur Haustür noch nicht übertreten hatte, nachbessern.

<sup>Quelle: [Welt Online](http://www.welt.de/print/die_welt/finanzen/article13061381/Fiskus-verschaerft-Regeln-fuer-reuige-Steuersuender.html)</sup>

Mit Mord haben aber die angeschuldigten Vergehen meist nichts zu tun. Woher kommt also dann diese recht drastische Redenswendung?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Wenn in katholischen Gebieten ein ungetauftes Kind starb, durfte es nicht auf dem Friedhof beerdigt werden. Als einziger gesegnete Ort, wo das Tote vor bösen Mächten geschützt blieb, galt das Elternhaus. Deshalb wurden dort heimlich tote Kinder im Keller begraben."
(aus [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eine_Leiche_im_Keller_haben))

Es ist amüsant, dass man im Englischen einen ähnlichen Ausdruck hat:

> To have a skeleton in the closet.

(Die [früheste Erscheinung](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=s&p=35) dieses  Ausdrucks ist 1845 bei  Thackeray zu finden.)

Comment: Cupboard is an even more eerie location

Comment: Ja Takkat, Du hast Recht. Notiz: Takkat spricht von einer früheren Version der Antwort, in der ich " a skeleton in the cupboard" geschrieben hatte . Ich habe "cupboard" zu "closet" modifiziert um Thackeray treu zu sein. Aber Takkats Bemerkung trifft immer noch zu...

Comment: Wenn man jetzt zynisch wäre, könnte man die Redewendung zu "Leiche in der Kühltruhe" ändern... :/

Comment: "Certainly there are thirteen bodies in the cellar and there are hundreds more in the attic!"

Comment: In Dutch, the bodies are also in 'de kast' (the closet).